# Why is Python version set with PyEnv global not picked up a default one?

Tags: macos, python, path, zsh

I have installed `pyenv` and used it to install Python 3.8.1 I had Python 3.7.6 installed manually before.

I have set 3.8.1 as `global` and, as this version is now markered with `*`, it was taken into account. However, `which python3` and `python3 -V` are still outputting the values of `3.7.6`! I have restarted the shell, but, unfortunately, the outputs are still the same.

Is this as expected behaviour? How to switch it to 3.8.1 properly?

NB `echo $PATH` outputs

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post your `cat ~/.bash_profile` output.

Comment: @ankii - added at the end of the question. I was using the zsh though, and there is no file for zsh in the root folder as far as I can see.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that(should have seen the tags) . user manual says modify ~/.zshrc instead of the bash_profile

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout

> Define environment variable PYENV_ROOT to point to the path where pyenv repo is cloned and add $PYENV_ROOT/bin to your $PATH for access to the pyenv command-line utility.

```
$ echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bash_profile
$ echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

> Zsh note: Modify your ~/.zshrc file instead of ~/.bash_profile.

-

> Add pyenv init to your shell to enable shims and autocompletion. Please make sure eval "$(pyenv init -)" is placed toward the end of the shell configuration file since it manipulates PATH during the initialization.

```
$ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n  eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Restart Shell

```
exec "$SHELL"
```

Comment: I also had to prepend `$HOME/.pyenv/shims` to my path.